# How to make a picture box appear randomly on the screen

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am coding a zombie game in vb.net and need to make the zombies(which I have put in picture boxes and an array, there are 13) appear randomly, maybe two each time 1 zombie is killed. How can I make this in code ? I am new to coding and cannot figure it out even after numerous searching.

Comment: So what have you tried, and where are you stuck?  Getting errors? Unexpected results?

Comment: I have been able to make the zombies move and also make the gunman fire shots as well as move, but have not been able to make the zombies appear randomly. I need to randomise the picture boxes, i.e make random zombies appear and i have to kill them.

Comment: You talk about "picture boxes" but this question is tagged ASP.NET, so you're making this confusing. Is it actually a WinForms application and you're using `PictureBox` controls or is it Web Forms and you're actually using `Image` controls or is it something else? You need to be precise in your language because we only know what you tell us so telling us contradictory things makes it hard to provide an answer.

Comment: So, getting back to the original comment then.  Any chance you could update your question with the code where you're creating the picture boxes maybe?

Comment: Oh sorry @jmcilhinney, I am using windows forms to create a 2D game

Comment: @Hursey I have dragged and dropped a picture box from toolbar and set an image from properties.

Comment: Your question is too broad. You need to make an attempt and ask a question if what you do doesn't. As a hint, you use the `Random` class to generate random numbers and then use them in whatever way is appropriate for your application, e.g. the X and Y coordinates of the `Location` of a control.

Comment: Well really we need more detail.  Dropping a picture box on the designer really tells us nothing.  As @jmcilhinney says, you will need to use the Random class to create the coords etc. for your picture box, best done when creating picture boxes at runtime rather than design time

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to do.

You'll want to construct a picture box in code then define where you want it to "spawn" on your form.

You can start with something like this, if you're going to have more than one zombie at a time you'll want to either make a list of them or name them uniquely so you can reference them later on (moving them/despawning/etc)

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim zombie As New PictureBox
    With zombie
        zombie.Width = 100 'or the size you need
        zombie.Height = 100 ' same thing
        zombie.Top = 20 'or where you need it could be a random
        zombie.Left = 20 'same as top
        zombie.ImageLocation = "C:\mydocuments\zombie.png" 'change this to the location of your zombie image. if you're storing it in a resource you can call it here
    End With
    Me.Controls.Add(zombie)
End Sub
```

This should get you started at least

edit: I missed the part where you said you have an array for your zombies, but you can do an array of your picture boxes as well